# Split is not doing anything when used inside filter

Tags: javascript, filter, split, map-function

I tried using this function to filter an array based on index and return the splitted string into new array

```
const arr = ['arr 1','arr 2','arr 3','arr 4']
const newArr = arr.filter((val,index)=> {
  if(index <= 1) {
    return val.split(' ')
  }
})
```

newArr should return this,

```
[['arr','1'],['arr','2']]
```

But it return this,

```
["arr 1", "arr 2"]
```

Here is the code in JS BIN: https://jsbin.com/zoguwoyexe/edit?js,console

Split works inside map function, but I wonder why it doesn't work inside filter, anyone knows about this?

Comment: `filter` can't modify the array element, it can only include/exclude it from the new array being given back to you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`filter` expects you to return `true`-y or `false`-y values. It keeps trues and discards falses. It does not return the values you return, it returns a subset of the input array.

By using filter *and* map, like this, should get what you expect.

```
const arr = ['arr 1','arr 2','arr 3','arr 4']
const newArr = arr
  .filter((val,index) => (index <= 1))
  .map((val, index) => val.split(' '));
```

Comment: ooh okay, i understand, thank you for your explanation